# Ошибка PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR после смены SSL порта сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl

Есть работающий ASP.Net Core 5.0 проект, в котором решил поменять список используемых портов.

Был порт 44376:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54528",
      "sslPort": 44376
    }
  },
```

Поставил 48907.

И после старта приложения браузер не хочет подключаться, выдаёт ошибку:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:48907.
> PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

Почистил папку `.vs` - не помогло.

Что можно сделать в подобной ситуации?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64880715/12888024

Answer (score 1):

Помог запуск скрипта из ответа на en so: [HTTPS error in ASP.NET Core app running on IISExpress - PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64880715/5752652)

Скрипт перед запуском лучше модифицировать, т.к. сканируются порты в диапазоне от 44300 44399, лучше указать свои конкретные значения из проекта.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).log"
try {
    Write-Host "Creating cert resources"
    $ekuOidCollection = [System.Security.Cryptography.OidCollection]::new();
    $ekuOidCollection.Add([System.Security.Cryptography.Oid]::new("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1","Server Authentication")) | Out-Null
    $sanBuilder = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder]::new();
    $sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost") | Out-Null
    
    Write-Host "Creating cert extensions"
    $certificateExtensions = @(
        # Subject Alternative Name
        $sanBuilder.Build($true),        
        # ASP.NET Core OID
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension]::new(
            "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1",
            [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("IIS Express Development Certificate"),
            $false),
            # KeyUsage
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageExtension]::new(
                [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags]::KeyEncipherment,
                $true),
                # Enhanced key usage
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]::new(
            $ekuOidCollection,
            $true),
            # Basic constraints
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509BasicConstraintsExtension]::new($false,$false,0,$true)
        )
    Write-Host "Creating cert parameters"
    $parameters = @{
        Subject = "localhost";
        KeyAlgorithm = "RSA";
        KeyLength = 2048;
        CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My";
        KeyExportPolicy = "Exportable";
        NotBefore = Get-Date;
        NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(1);
        HashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        Extension = $certificateExtensions;
        SuppressOid = @("2.5.29.14");
        FriendlyName = "IIS Express Development Certificate"
    }
    Write-Host "Creating cert"
    $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @parameters

    $rootStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList Root, LocalMachine
    $rootStore.Open("MaxAllowed")
    $rootStore.Add($cert)
    $rootStore.Close()
    
    Write-Host "Creating port bindings"
    # Add an Http.Sys binding for port 44300-44399
    $command = 'netsh'
    for ($i=44300; $i -le 44399; $i++) {
        $optionsDelete = @('http', 'delete', 'sslcert', "ipport=0.0.0.0:$i")
        $optionsAdd = @('http', 'add', 'sslcert', "ipport=0.0.0.0:$i", "certhash=$($cert.Thumbprint)", 'appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a}')
        Write-Host "Running $command $optionsDelete"
        & $command $optionsDelete
        Write-Host "Running $command $optionsAdd"
        & $command $optionsAdd
    } 
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
finally {
    Stop-Transcript
}
```

Также рекомендую почитать исходный issue на github'е — тоже много полезной информации: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26437

Comment: Почему бы не запостить скрипт прямо в ответ?

Comment: @aepot Действительно, чего это я?.. Добавил.